# How to printf a time_t variable as a floating point number?

Tags: c, time, parallel-processing, openmp, time-t

I'm using a time_t variable in C (openMP enviroment) to keep cpu execution time...I define a float value sum_tot_time to sum time for all cpu's...I mean sum_tot_time is the sum of cpu's time_t values. The problem is that printing the value sum_tot_time it appear as an integer or long, by the way without its decimal part!

I tried in these ways:

1. to printf sum_tot_time as a double being a double value
2. to printf sum_tot_time as float being a float value
3. to printf sum_tot_time as double being a time_t value
4. to printf sum_tot_time as float being a time_t value

Comment: Why do you assume the sum of your time_t's will have a decimal part ?

Comment: Guys, Thank you very much for your help. I'm gonna answer to nos as well. I was coding a routine using parallel cpu's with sharing memory.  I needed to check times of execution with one two or more cpu's or cores. Considering that milliseconds are very important for distinguishing efficiency. 
I've used the difference between 2 omp_get_wtime(), before and just after the parallel region. The  function returns a double-precision floating point value equal to the elapsed wall clock time in seconds since some "time in the past", that do not change during the execution of the application program.

Answer (score 3):

The resolution of `time_t` is at most one second on most platforms.  That is, on most platforms, `time_t` *will* be an integer (32- or 64-bit) value counting the number of seconds elapsed since midnight of Jan 1st 1970 (UTC), and can only achieve one-second resolution.

Therefore, a sum of `time_t` values will also only exhibit one-second resolution (no decimal part, even after converting to `double`.)

The above having been said, **what native or OpenMP call are you using to obtain the `time_t` values that you are attempting to accumulate?**

If using either the native *nix [`getrusage()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) call to fill out an `rusage` structure (provided your platform supports it) with user/kernel times, or if using [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) to get wall time, then use both the `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` fields of `struct timeval` to generate a `double` value (of millisecond-or-better resolution, typically), and use that instead of `time_t` in your calculations:

```
struct timeval {
        time_t          tv_sec;         /* seconds */
        suseconds_t     tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
};
```

Correspondingly, you can use `GetThreadTimes`/`GetProcessTimes` for user/kernel times or `_ftime` for wall time on Windows platforms, then combine `FILETIME::dwHighDateTime/dwLowDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have access to standard *nix system calls ( or if this is relevant to specifically to what you're doing ), but if you do you can use the `timeval struct` and `gettimeofday`.    For example, to print out a timestamp with six decimal places of precision which produces a tcpdump style time stamp ( [courtesy of Steven UNP](http://www.unpbook.com) )

```
#include    "unp.h"
#include    <time.h>

char *
gf_time(void)
{
    struct timeval  tv;
    time_t          t;
    static char     str[30];
    char            *ptr;

    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) < 0)
        err_sys("gettimeofday error");

    t = tv.tv_sec;  /* POSIX says tv.tv_sec is time_t; some BSDs don't agree. */
    ptr = ctime(&t);
    strcpy(str, &ptr[11]);
        /* Fri Sep 13 00:00:00 1986\n\0 */
        /* 0123456789012345678901234 5  */
    snprintf(str+8, sizeof(str)-8, ".%06ld", tv.tv_usec);

    return(str);
}
```